# Problem with importing from Cludes ERP System to Magento backend

Tags: magento2, api, import

I  am importing products from Cludes  **ERP** System,  but Product base image is not set in Magento backend:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to download a sample file from Magento and make sure you add all required headers and values for adding the product as base_image, small_image etc